# Is it possible to host QGIS on a computing server?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, performance, noise

I'm working on a project with QGIS Desktop 3.18.3. My plugin always crashes.

Is it possible to host QGIS on a computing server? If so, will it improve the performance?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What do you mean by "computing server" *exactly* in terms of hard- and software?

Comment: Instead of QGIS on a computing server, you may want to look into using python, R, gdal or another command line interface (CLI) or programming language for spatial operations. Often the desktop operations are able to be scripted.

Comment: There are some tasks that even hundreds of CPUs and terabytes of RAM can't fix. Without a specific task, and a specific configuration, it's impossible to predict (even with these, it's *nearly* impossible to predict).

Comment: Do you mean cloud server, as in SAAS

Comment: You may want to look at https://qgiscloud.com/

Comment: @bugmenot123 
Hi, thanks for replying to my question. Apologies for the late reply.

To clarify, this is an example of the Server we have:

Operating System: Linux 
GPU: Nvidia P100
vCPU cores:16
Memory: 64GB
Storage: 300GB

We are wondering if running QGIS on such server would help the speed and process.

Thank you!

Comment: @nmtoken 
Hi, thanks for replying to my question. Apologies for the late reply.

To clarify, this is an example of the Server we have:

Operating System: Linux 
GPU: Nvidia P100
vCPU cores:16
Memory: 64GB
Storage: 300GB

We are wondering if running QGIS on such server would help the speed and process.

Thank you!

Comment: @GISHuman
Hi, thanks for replying to my question. Apologies for the late reply.

To clarify, this is an example of the Server we have:

Operating System: Linux 
GPU: Nvidia P100
vCPU cores:16
Memory: 64GB
Storage: 300GB

We are wondering if running QGIS on such server would help the speed and process.

Thank you!

Comment: @Vince 
Hi, thanks for replying to my question. Apologies for the late reply.

To clarify, this is an example of the Server we have:

Operating System: Linux 
GPU: Nvidia P100
vCPU cores:16
Memory: 64GB
Storage: 300GB

We are wondering if running QGIS on such server would help the speed and process.

Thank you!

Comment: Posting the same comment over again isn't going to help here.

Comment: Instead of commenting on your own question you should [edit] it to address any clarifications sought by the commenters and/or to add any additional information relevant to your question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the plugin crashes QGIS because the computations need too much memory, it will help to move to a computer with more RAM.

(QGIS Server is a web map server application. It is not focused on the kind of task described in this thread.)

Comment: Thank you, do you know if it's possible to host QGIS on a computing server?